# Determining Uniform Convergence

Tags: real-analysis

I wish to determine if $f_{n}(x) = x^2 - \frac{x^n}{n}$ with $x \in [0,1], n\in \mathbb{N}$ is uniformly convergent. Likewise, I also wish to determine if $f'_{n}(x)$ is uniformly convergent.

First, we must find a candidate for uniform limit of $f_{n}(x)$ to determine if it is uniformly convergent. It's limits are $$1 \;:\;x=\pm 1$$

$$ x^2 \; : \; |x|<1$$

$$DNE \; : \; |x|>1$$

Do I check each case to see if it is uniformly convergent there?

So we have: $\forall_{\epsilon > 0} \exists_{N(\epsilon)} \forall_{x \in [0,1]} \forall_{n \geq N} \left ( |f_{n}(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon\right)$

Then checking the first case we check that $$|(x^2 - \frac{x^n}{n}) - 1| < \epsilon$$ but that simplifies to $$|nx^2 - x^n - n|$$ which cannot be less than $\epsilon$ since $n \to \infty$, we get $\infty$ on the LHS.

Do I continue like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_n(x)$ converges pointwise to $f(x) = x^2$ on $[0,1]$ and $$|f_n(x) - f(x)| = \left|\frac{x^n}{n}\right| \leq \frac{1}{n}$$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ so the convergence is indeed uniform.

For the derivative $f_n'(x) = 2x - x^{n-1}$ which converges pointwise to $g(x) = 2x$ for $x<1$ and $g(x) = 2x - 1 = 1$ for $x=1$. Since $g$ is not continuous the convergence cannot be uniform. This can also be seen directly from considering $|f_n'(x) - g(x)| = |x^{n-1}|$.

Comment: Regarding your edit, should we not only consider $g(x) = 2x$ since we are restricted to $x \in [0,1]$? In that case we have $$|2x - x^{n-1} - 2x | = |x^{n-1}|$$ Which, since $|x|<1$, $x^{n-1} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Therefore, $f'_{n}(x)$ is uniformly convergent.

Comment: @JonRol For the first part you are right except at the point $x=1$ where $x^n = 1$ so this term does contribute to the limit. For the second part note that we need $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_n' - g| \to 0$ in order for the convergence to be uniform so just noting that $x^{n-1}$ goes to $0$ for every single $x<1$-value is not enough. In fact $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_n' - g| = 1$ and so is the limit.